# why css width property is changing with display:inline property?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, display

i have piece of code which contain an `<ul>` element and the `<ul`> element have a css property `display:block` by default.here is the code snippet,

```css
ul,li{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
/*display:inline;*/
}
#parent{
  width:100%;
  /*height:50px;*/
  background-color:red;
  }
  
  #child{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    }
    
#grand-child-1,#grand-child-2 {
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
#grand-child-2{
  background-color:green;
}
#grand-child-1{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
   <ul id="child">
     <li id="grand-child-1">title 1</li>
     <li id="grand-child-2">title-2</li>
     <li id="grand-child-3">title-3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but when i added `display:inline` to the  tag to remove it's default `display:block` property , then the width property of grand-child-1,grand-child-2 is changed.i added the snippet below.how to fix this problem?.thanks is advance.

```css
ul,li{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
display:inline;
}
#parent{
  width:100%;
  /*height:50px;*/
  background-color:red;
  }
  
  #child{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    }
    
#grand-child-1,#grand-child-2 {
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
#grand-child-2{
  background-color:green;
}
#grand-child-1{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
   <ul id="child">
     <li id="grand-child-1">title 1</li>
     <li id="grand-child-2">title-2</li>
     <li id="grand-child-3">title-3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `li` `display: inline` (or `display: inline-block`) but **NOT** the `ul`. Like this:

```
li {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  display:inline; /* or inline block */
}
```

The entire code:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}

#parent {
  width: 100%;
  /*height:50px;*/
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#grand-child-1,
#grand-child-2 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#grand-child-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#grand-child-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <ul id="child">
    <li id="grand-child-1">title 1</li>
    <li id="grand-child-2">title-2</li>
    <li id="grand-child-3">title-3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry bro ,I'm thinking that give 'display:inline;'  property to <li> element it will not remove the block property created by <ul> element.

Comment: or else can you please answer with the help of a snippet

Comment: If you try the code I gave you, you will get the effect you wanted. Making the ul and inline element will damage your design. Why do you want (or need) to make the ul an inline?

Comment: i would like to remove the unwanted space created by <ul> element,that is why i used display:inline

Comment: That space is remove with: `ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` Again, see my answer; I posted the entire code.